# vue button related event not fired

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, modal-dialog, vue-component

In:

https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hodgkin-qjt61?file=/src/components/EditCategory.vue

the modal is shown as expected upon long click over a category:

[image]

but clicking `OK` does not fire the `close` event:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-longclick="() => longClicked()" @click="longClicked()">
      {{ taskItemLocal["name"] }}
    </p>
    <div v-if="this.showModal" @close="closeModal()">
      <transition name="modal">
        <div class="modal-mask">
          <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <div class="modal-container">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <slot name="header"> Edit Category </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                <slot name="name"> Edit Name </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                <slot name="delete"> Delete Category </slot>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <slot name="footer">
                  <!-- default footer -->
                  <!-- EVENT NOT FIRING -->
                  <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                    OK
                  </button>
                </slot>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`closeModal()` is not called; changing `showModal` "directly" also fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen to an event within the component that emitted that event, you use the instance `$on` method:

```
  mounted() {
    this.$on("close", () => {
      this.closeModal();
    });
  }
```

The template event handler `@close="closeModal()"` is used to listen to events from parent. It has no effect within the child component.

The working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-kirch-vrhwn?file=/src/components/EditCategory.vue .

Comment: Strange. So the event was not called because the component has not yet been mounted?

Comment: No. in mounted hook I just created the event listener. The event has always been called. the difference is in how you listen to it in component and in the parent component. in component you use `this.$on('event', handler)`  to create a listener, in parent you use `v-on:event` or `@event` prop.

Comment: That makes it clear. However, can there be a case when there is an event fired and the component has yet to register its receiver?

Comment: if there are events fired right after it is mounted, and you are registering the listeners latter (in a watcher for example), then yes, you can end up with a similar situation. however, you have full control over when and how you are firing and listening to events, so I would say there should be no unexpected cases.  registering the listeners in `mounted`, gives you full confidence that no events will be missed simply because the DOM starts firing events only after it is mounted, when the listener is already created.

Answer (score 2):

You have dispatch event to parent but in parent component you have not done any thing with "close" event. Here, in GenericItem.vue I have made event listener with @close="closeBox($event)" . Here, it will trigger method of closeBox

**GenericItem.vue**

*Changes on Template*

```
 <edit-category
  v-if="editCategoryStatus"
  :taskItem="taskItemLocal"
  @close="closeBox($event)"
/>
```

*Add one closeBox method*

```
closeBox() {
  this.editCategoryStatus = !this.editCategoryStatus;
},
```

Add editCategoryStatus on data

```
 data() {
return {
  editCategoryStatus: true,
  taskItemLocal: {
    type: Object,
    default: {},
  },
};
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The `edit-category` component is emitting the event just fine– the parent just isn't actually listening for it. Adding `@close=". . ."` to the `<edit-category>` tag is the key part that's missing in OPs code.

Comment: Correct! This would be the next step (at the moment I've wanted to see how can I make a component listen to events emitted to itself).

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your button like this. You made this more complicated than it should be

```
<button class="modal-default-button" @click="showModal = false">
```

Also, there is this example from the official docs
[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-modal-component?from-embed=&file=/index.html:1327-1353).

Comment: That was the initial code and it failed; added a function for clarity (console.log). It fails regardless. It works when instead of emitting an event, I toggle `showModal` directly.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-rain-7fzb9?file=/src/components/EditCategory.vue:871-935 it's working

Comment: Yes, this works. But I want to have the event working instead (the modal will have to talk to a parent component at some point).

Comment: Oh so you want to run the closeModal func? When you emit a custom event like yours close event it's not going to run the closeModal func. you should do it like @click="closeModal()" and there is no need for the custom close event that you added like this https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-rain-7fzb9?file=/src/components/EditCategory.vue

Comment: Yes, there is no need now but will be tomorrow. The example is taken from here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-tdd-jrrgg?file=/index.html
I want to do the same thing with single file components.