# Events not being received by parent component vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-events

Based on:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-data-back-to-parent/1201
[vue button related event not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68321795/vue-button-related-event-not-fired/68322941#68322941)

I have:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-mendeleev-hi4br?file=/src/components/GenericItem.vue

where the parent listens for events emitted by a child component:

```
  mounted() {
    this.$on("edit-category", (taskItemParam) => {
      console.log("Received edit-category event with payload:", taskItemParam);
    });
    this.$on("delete-category", (taskItemParam) => {
      console.log(
        "Received delete-category event with payload:",
        taskItemParam
      );
    });
  },
```

where the child:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-mendeleev-hi4br?file=/src/components/EditCategory.vue

emits two events:

```
  <div class="modal-body" @click="emitEditCategory()">
    <slot name="name"> Edit Name </slot>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body" @click="emitDeleteCategory()">
    <slot name="delete"> Delete Category </slot>
  </div>

  methods: {
    ...
    emitEditCategory() {
      this.$emit("edit-category", this.taskItemLocal);
      console.log("Emitting edit-category");
    },
    emitDeleteCategory() {
      this.$emit("delete-category", this.taskItemLocal);
      console.log("Emitting delete-category");
    },
  },
```

Why don't the events reach the parent? What's the scope of an event in vue (w.r.t. child-to-parent depth)

Comment: What's wrong with calling them in mounted? They are not.

Comment: Scope of events in Vue is just child to parent. They don't bubble or anything ...from this POV the name "event" is a wrong choice as the events in Vue are nothing else then method calls...

Comment: Going through the docs again it's not clear in what way the current example differs from the one there; (aside from having registered the listeners in the template).

Comment: @Michal Levý  Is there something like a broadcast scheme (not necessarily event bus (vuex))?

Comment: There is no such a thing build in to Vue. Even the "event bus" pattern was [stripped out in Vue 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#overview)

Comment: Even so, `GenericItem` is the parent of `EditCategory`: `  <div v-if="taskItemLocal['itemSectionCategoryId']">
    <edit-category :taskItem="taskItemLocal" />
  </div>` Shouldn't the events be received by the parents (since it's one hop away from the child).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.$on` is trying to listener to the events emitted by the `this` component, so it's listening to itself.

Note that this api (`$on`) shouldn't really be used. It has been removed from Vue3 and leads to a badly designed vue application.

To listen to your child component events, use `v-on`, or the shortand syntax `@my-event`:

```html
<template>
   <edit-category :taskItem="taskItemLocal" @edit-category="updateCategory" @delete-category="deleteCategory"/>
</template>

<script>
[...]
   methods: {
      updateCategory(task) {
         // Do what you want
      }
      deleteCategory(task) {
         // Do what you want
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: This works, but if you have multiple events, say for a text editor, for example, the code just looks plain ugly. Is there any way of encapsulation/syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Sebi you can use object syntax to pass a multile event listeners at once - the technique is hinted [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) and works similar as passing multiple [pros as an object](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object)